# Why these solutions are different?

Tags: r, inference

I'm trying to solve this question:

---

Across nine European countries in a large-scale survey, people had a hard time identifying signs of a stroke or heart attack. The survey included 10,228 inhabitants of Austria, France, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands, Poland, Russia, Spain, and the United Kingdom. Participants ages ranged from 14 to 98. Of those surveyed, less than half (4910) linked arm or shoulder pain to heart attacks. Use a software to find and interpret a 99% confidence interval for the proportion of Europeans (from these nine countries) who can identify arm or shoulder pain as a symptom of a heart attack.

---

I've been solving this question in two ways:

**First solution:**

s=c(rep(1,4910), rep(0,10228-4910))

x = sum(c(rep(1,4910), rep(0,10228-4910))==1)/10228

y = sum(c(rep(1,4910), rep(0,10228-4910))==1)/10228

for(i in 1:1000)
{
x = append(x,sum(sample(s,10228, replace = T)==1)/10228)
}

z = qnorm(1-(0.01/2))

#The 99% confidence interval

y-z*sd(x)

y+z*sd(x)

**Second solution:**

#The 99% confidence interval

quantile(x,c(0.01,0.99))

I didn't understand why these solutions are different.

Comment: You are making different assumptions in each. You should use relevant parametric methods (solution one) where you have good reason to suspect the underlying processes are parametric and non parametric (solution 2) when you don't. Parametric and non-parametric methods are influenced by noise and error differently, so will differ.

Comment: Also, in last method, doesn't `quantile(x,c(0.01,0.99))` give a 98% CI.

Comment: Wald interval: `p=4910/10228; q = qnorm(c(.005,.995)); p + q*sqrt(p*(1-p)/10228)` gives $(0.4673301 0.4927794).$ Jeffreys interval: `qbeta(c(.005,.995), 4910.5, 5318.5)` gives $(0.4673417, 0.4927863).$ // For comparison.

Comment: @BruceET but I want the 99% CI.

Comment: Examples of CIs in my comment just above _are_ 99%. But it seems to me your code at the end makes a 98% CI

Comment: @ReneBt I think the introductory book I'm using (Statistics: Unlocking the Power of Data by Lock) doesn't make this distinction, he gives the solution 2 to this problem and sometimes in other similar problems gives solution 1. When we study these concepts (parametric and non parametric methods)? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Lock$^5$ are intent on showing the broad application of certain computationally intensive methods---and good for them. I'm a great fan of simulation methods, but IMHO they sometimes get carried away with their program. A sledge hammer will open a lot of things, including a soda can, but sometimes with a soda can the pull tab is just easier (and less messy). This problem is a soda can.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you very much Bruce.